# How to add Map values in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app and trying to use Firebase Realtime Database to store the scores for my game. My database has many users, each of which contains a TreeMap with the date as the key and the score as the value. I am trying to have the player click a button and save their score inside the TreeMap. I am having trouble with reading the data in the TreeMap because I want this to be a one time read and not a listener.

I have tried retrieving the map first, updating it, and reuploading it to the database. However, I don't know how to link this to the button click, as online tutorials all seem to use a listener and snapshot.

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        String name = "";
        String age = "";
        String number = "";
        TreeMap<String, Integer> scores = new TreeMap<>();

        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User user = new User();
            if (ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getScores() != null){
                ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getScores().put(date, totalScore);
                scores = ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getScores();
            }
            name = ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getUserName();
            age = ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getUserAge();
            number = ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getUserPhoneNumber();

        }

        scores.put(date, totalScore);
        User temp = new User(userID, name, age, number, scores);
        myRef.child(userID).setValue(temp);
    }
```

This is the solution I had written, but it doesn't incorporate the button click.

Answer (score 2):

```
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapShot.getValue(User.class);
                    if(user.getScores()!=null){
                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                           hashMap.put("date", date);
                           hashMap.put("totalScore", totalScore);
                           query.child(userId).setValue(hashMap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

this is how you update the score , you didnt show ur database schema so i i am not clearly give you the exact query.